# Use inline img width instead of css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hy,

I'm developing a responsive webpage, and I just wondering if there is a solution to use the inline img attributes instead of the css?

Here is an example:

```
<img src="picture.jpg" height="90" width="120" alt="picture alt" />
```

But the mobile-first css use the next css:

```
width: auto; height: auto; max-width: 80%;
```

The outcome is the picture width is the original width of it. (if the picture width is 800px, than it will be displayed as 800px width)

How can it be fixed to use the width and height attribute?

Thanks, Dave.

Comment: You want it to respect it's width/height attributes? Remove the css changing it's width/height.

Comment: If you want the max width to be a percentage of the div it is in, you will need to specify the width of the outer div in % as well.

Comment: @evu - I can't remove it, because it's mobile first. It controls the mobile display.

Comment: @PhilM. - I don't have problems with the max-width, I have problems with the height and width.

Comment: I made a mistake by mixing width and height up, my argument remains the same though.

Comment: On old mobiles the media queries does not work. Because of that, I write my css for these mobiles and build up media queries for PC. I use "min-width" not "max-width".

Answer (score 1):

Inline CSS should override it.

```
<img src="picture.jpg" style="height:90px; width:120px;" alt="picture alt" />
```

Comment: The page content will be uploaded by none-programers, so the inline css not the best answer :\

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have two different displays: one for regular computers and one for mobile devices.  It won't matter what classes you assign if you're using inline CSS.  Inline CSS will override everything, so don't use it unless you want to use JavaScript to manually override the styles.

Instead, give your image elements a certain class so we can target them with CSS:

```
<img src="picture.jpg" height="90" width="120" class="ResizeableImage" alt="picture alt" />
```

Now, create a mobile CSS class for each screen width that you want to target:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: ???px) {
    .ResizeableImage 
        { 
            //Put Mobile Styling Here 
        }
}
```

Your question was a little hard to understand, so I hope this is what you're looking for.  If not, leave a comment and I'll try to help.

Comment: Also, this link will probably be helpful for you: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly, BUT! I developing in mobile first. What means, first I write the stylesheet to the mobile devices, THAN use media queries to the tablet and PC. And because of that, the mobile CSS override the `height` and `width` attributes of the image.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  Why doesn't this answer work for your solution?